# Smartsheet - An error occurred during SSL handshake

Tags: smartsheet-api

It would be extremely useful to replace our existing interface with Smartsheets, since the client already uses Smartsheets and our prototype is a bit clunky. To that end, I'm building a prototype in order to the learn the Smartsheet API, and it breaks when I try to set up a webhook.

Here's the output when I attempt to update/enable a webhook:

```
{"message": "SUCCESS",
 "resultCode": 0,
 "result": {

"id": 4253946970695556,
"name": "Webhook_test",
"apiClientId": "3oqnphhimgqzyimk40",
"apiClientName": "ChoiceIP",
"scope": "sheet",
"scopeObjectId": 7055538769946500,
"events": [
  "*.*"
],
"callbackUrl": "https://ghwd.net/write_requests_to_log.php",
"sharedSecret": "kpnc4nz7gwy91yjzcah2s6neq",
"enabled": false,
"status": "DISABLED_VERIFICATION_FAILED",
"disabledDetails": "An error occurred during SSL handshake. (ref id: fwhc0949r7km)",
"version": 1,
"createdAt": "2016-07-06T12:04:13Z",
"modifiedAt": "2016-07-07T06:04:20Z"
  }
}
```

Here's the code from the script that is supposed to create a response:

```
$headers = getallheaders();

if( isset( $headers['smartsheet-hook-challenge'] ) ) {

 header("Smartsheet-Hook-Response: " . $headers['smartsheet-hook-challenge']);
 echo $headers['smartsheet-hook-challenge'];
 return;

} else if( isset( $_POST['smartsheet-hook-challenge'] ) ) {

header("Smartsheet-Hook-Response: " . $_POST['smartsheet-hook-challenge']);
echo $_POST['smartsheet-hook-challenge'];
return;

} else {

 header("Smartsheet-Hook-Response: debug");

}
```

Why is the SSL handshake failing?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to have a valid SSL certificate setup for the domain ghwd.net or use a domain that has a valid SSL certificate.

When you create a webhook, Smartsheet will first try to connect to your callback URL over a secure connection. If a secure connection cannot be made the webhook will be disabled with the status you are seeing, `DISABLED_VERIFICATION_FAILED`.

[Smartsheet Webhook Documentation](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#webhooks)

Comment: To add to Brett's answer, Smartsheet doesn't support self-signed certificates. It must be signed by a third party CA. We've just updated the documentation to make a note of that.